# Limit of the limit of a sequence of functions at a point

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function for each $n$ such that
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f_n(x) = f_n(0) = 0$$
and 
$$f_n(x) \to f(x)$$ pointwise where $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ exists and $$f(0) = 0.$$
Does it follow that $$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0?$$

Do I need some uniform convergence result for this or do the assumptions suffice? I don't know whether $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x)=nx$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 1 n$ and $1$ for $ x > \frac 1 n$. Let $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then all the conditions are satisfied and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) \neq f(0)$.

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly in some interval $(0,\delta)$ then the conclusion is true.